# django ckeditor takes whole site with saving buttons

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm trying to set django-suit-ckeditor for TextField in django admin but it takes whole content-title div with 'saving' buttons instead of a single field. It works for every other field.
Just like here http://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wysiwyg.html
Any one knows the reason?

Here's screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW7LV.png
and here's my code:

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'content': CKEditorWidget(editor_options={'startupFocus': True})
        }

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostForm
    fieldsets = [
        ('Content', {'fields': ('content',)})
    ]


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

I would be grateful for any help.

**EDIT:**
I've solved problem by using django-ckeditor not django-suit-ckeditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is still interested - there are some name clashing causes this. Just rename your field from `content` to anything else.